# How to update a value

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So, i'm building a bank simulator that includes everything i learned so far, i just wanna take that piece of code to another level, until its power get to over 9000. (Props for DBZ reference!) I'm looking for a way in my piece of code, to update the value of the balance after operation. Because right now, after an operation, my value is resetted and I don't want that.
And also, by the same occasion, give me some pointers, tips to make the code shorter, more readable, to add more depth to it!

---

```
using System;

namespace Bank
{
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        double balance = 2000;
        bool exit = true;
        Console.WriteLine("|----------Welcome to the Nobody's Poor Bank!----------|");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("You actually have 2000$ in your bank account.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        while (exit==true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What operation would you like to do?\n");
            Console.Write("(W) Withdraw  (D) Deposit  (E) Exit : ");
            string choice = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (choice)
            {
                case "W":
                case "w":
                    Console.Write("\nHow much money would you like to withdraw? : ");
                    string WithdrawAmount = Console.ReadLine();
                    double WithdrawValue;
                    double.TryParse(WithdrawAmount, out WithdrawValue);
                    balance -= WithdrawValue;
                    Console.WriteLine("\nAfter the operation, your balance is now " + balance + "$");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.Clear();
                    break;

                case "D":
                case "d":
                    Console.Write("\nHow much money would you like to deposit? : ");
                    string DepositAmount = Console.ReadLine();
                    double DepositValue;
                    double.TryParse(DepositAmount, out DepositValue);
                    balance += DepositValue;
                    Console.WriteLine("\nAfter the operation, your balance is now " + balance + "$");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.Clear();
                    break;

                case "E":
                case "e":
                    Console.WriteLine("\nThank you for using our services!");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    exit = false;
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("\nThat is not a valid input...");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.Clear();
                    break;                                                             
            }
        }                
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: Not sure I see a question other than `balance -= WithdrawValue;`. Please be a bit clearer about what you are having trouble with. (And your `exit` flag is back-to-front, so confusing to the average reader)

Comment: You don't appear to actually be updating `balance`, just using it in the calculations in the `switch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code below, you are just calculating what the balance result should be, instead of actually updating it.

```
Console.WriteLine(
    "\nAfter the operation, your balance is now " + 
    (balance - WithdrawValue) + "$");
```

Try changing this to

```
balance -= WithdrawValue;
Console.WriteLine("\nAfter the operation, your balance is now " + balance + "$");
```

The first line updates the balance variable with the expected result.
The second line now just outputs the new value of balance to the Console.

Answer (score 0):

1) Declare your balance as static on the program class not on the main thread
Like

```
Static double balance = 2000;
```

This will update the balance value for the lifetime of the session of the programm run

2) instead of using d and D for your  switch cases you can use

```
Switch(choice.ToUpper())
 Case : "D"
```

This will convert the choice to Uppercase so you will only test capital letter D or B or whatever. This means that if the user enters d or D it will still give the same output.

3) Using a switch statement means that you want the application to act in a certain way if ancondition is true.....so you dont need to have console, readkey on all the case because only one will be exectuted at a time

Rather put that code after the switch and display after that like this,

```
Switch(Choice.ToUpper())
{ case : "D"
//some code..........
break;

case : "F"
//some code..........
break;
}
Console.WriteLine(balance.ToString());
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Making the variable static will **not** make it update the balance during the execution of the program.  Unless the value has to be updated by the program, and nothing in your answer addresses that.  In the case of this program, there is really no reason to mark the variable as `static`.  It's a console application with a single user running in a single instance.

Comment: Well thanks for these bits of information, this is all really helpful ;)